# Django delete multiple ImageField files on model delete

Tags: django, django-models

I have an Image model with two ImageFields (one for regular image and one for the thumbnail). I'm trying to delete both files together with a post_delete receiver but I'm having difficulty chaining the operations.

What I have throws a file does not exist error probably because only one delete saves.

```
class Image(models.Model):
    path = models.ImageField(upload_to=photo_image_upload_path,blank=False, null=False)
    thumb = models.ImageField(upload_to='', editable=False, default=None, null=True)

@receiver(post_delete, sender=Image)
def photo_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # Pass false so FileField doesn't save the model.
    if instance.thumb is not None:
        instance.thumb.delete(True)
    if instance.path is not None:
        instance.path.delete(False)
```

Comment: Do you try to delete the images from the media folder?

Comment: I'm trying to make it delete both images when the model is deleted